# Is there a way to disable LLVM assertions when running a user-defined pass?

Tags: error-handling, llvm

When running a user-defined LLVM pass, even if the pass starts with

```
#define NDEBUG
#include <assert.h>
```

the assertion in LLVM will still be checked.  I would like to disable the assertion when running the user-defined LLVM pass. For example, my pass invokes  [Value.cpp](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Value_8cpp_source.html), which in turn checks this assertion

`assert(Ty && "Value defined with a null type: Error!");`

Is that possible to disable that assertion? For information, one work-around would be to re-compile LLVM with flag `--disable-asserion`, but I am looking for less invasive solutions.

Comment: not a direct answer to your question, but I would suggest you to compile llvm/clang as shared libraries. This is 10 times faster than compiling as a static library.